# how to set ROS_MASTER_URI to the wireless address instead of IP

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to stablish bi-directional connection between  workstation and a netbook of a Turtlebot robot. The netbook uses the school wireless network and I can not get an static IP for it however it is accessible through a wireless address like turtle.dynamic.blabla.edu.
The instructions to set the ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI are based on using IP address, is ti possible to use wireless name/address instead of IP and if yes, how should I do it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39945/how-to-set-ros_master_uri-to-the-wireless-address-instead-of-ip/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You can use a resolvable wireless address as well, as long as both the workstation and the turtlebot can run something like `ping turtle.dynamic.blabla.edu` successfully.

If you followed the instructions here:
http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup, you can simply replace the `IP_OF_TURTLEBOT` with your resolvable address and re-run the instructions. This might cause duplicate entries in your `~/.bashrc` file which you can manually edit to retain only the relevant entries.

Once you have done so, follow the instructions at the end of the Network setup page to verify connectivity.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0